# Sum and Difference of columns in Ms-Acess in Two different tables

Tags: ms-access

Table : StudentTuitionFee

### GradeLevel   TuitionFee    MiscFee   RegistrationFee  BooksFee

Grade 1        25,000.00    5,000.00     3,000.00      3,500.00

Table : StudentRegistration

### Gradelevel StudentID

Grade 1    50090

Table : Student Profile

### StudentID   Name

50090       Oliver

Table : Payment

### StudentID   OR#   TuitionPay  MiscFeePay   RegistrationFeePay   BookFeepay

50090        1       5,000.00   500.00        500.00                500.00

50090        2       5,000.00   500.00        500.00                500.00

I'm creating a form that will show the data using the student id which I already able to show in the forms.

My Question is how to calculate the Difference from the StudentTuitionFee table and the Payment table. Using only the StudentID 50090.

The difference of TuitionFee, MiscFee, RegistrationFee and BookFee against all payments done in Payment table on TuitionFeepay, MiscFeePay, RegistrationFeePay and BookFeepay.

Comment: You want to calculate for each transaction type for each student? Build 2 queries that summarize both tables. Join the payments query to fees query with compound link on student ID and payment type. Include the student table to pull in name info.

Comment: Thank you suggestion. I will try learn first how to build query. :-)